# How can I sort list of map by map value in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I need to sort list of map, using value of map.

```
list = [
  %{id: 3, name: "Abe", count: 50},
  %{id: 1, name: "Bill", count: 10},
  %{id: 2, name: "Candy", count: 2},
]
```

For example, I need that list sorted by `id`:

```
list = [
  %{id: 1, name: "Bill", count: 10},
  %{id: 2, name: "Candy", count: 2},
  %{id: 3, name: "Abe", count: 50},
]
```

...or by `count` or `name`. How I can do it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's [`Enum.sort_by`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#sort_by/3) function, which accepts `list`, `mapper` and `sorter`. The following code does the trick:

```
list = [
  %{id: 3, name: "Abe", count: 50},
  %{id: 1, name: "Bill", count: 10},
  %{id: 2, name: "Candy", count: 2},
]

Enum.sort_by list, &Map.fetch(&1, :id)
```

we need to provide `list` and a function which returns the attribute of mapping. `Map.fetch(&1, :id)` returns a value by key, or even simpler:

```
Enum.sort_by list, & &1.id
```

`sorter` by default is `<=/2` function, which sorts the list in asc order.

Comment: too tempting to add this link https://stackoverflow.com/q/51787410/7852283 where you can see that `Enum.sort_by` and `Enum.sort` are not equivalent choices in a matter of performances. It helped me understand the plus value of `Enum.sort_by`.

Answer (score 10):

@IgodDrozdov provided a good solution. A more basic one: you can use [`Enum.sort/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#sort/2):

```
Enum.sort(list, &(&1.id < &2.id))
```

2nd argument must define a binary relation (like `sorter` in [`Enum.sort_by/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#sort_by/3))

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the performance/speed benefit of `Enum.sort` over `Enum.sort_by`. In our case the code ends up more compact too.