# Fast case-insensitive sorting in Elixir

Tags: elixir

Hi fellow Elixir programmers.

I have list of about 2.500 music tracks that I would like to sort by different parameters, for example the title of the track.

The sorting should be case insensitive.

The code below works, but takes about 100ms to 130ms to sort the list. Is there a faster way to do it? A reference for me is Node.js which does it in about 25ms when using `Array.prototype.sort`

Edit: Sorry, I actually mistimed the performance. The sorting happens in about 30ms. However, I would still like your opinion: Can the sorting be done faster?

Thanks.

```
defmodule MusicServer.Tracks.SortTracks do
  def sort_tracks(tracks, "title", "desc") do
    Enum.sort(tracks, fn track1, track2 ->
      first_char(track1["title"]) <= first_char(track2["title"])
    end)
  end

  def first_char(string) do
    string
    |> String.at(0)
    |> String.downcase()
  end
end
```

An example of the data structure:

```
[
  %{
    "artist" => "Rolling Stones",
    "title" => "Start It Up",
    "bpm" => 100,
    "createdAt" => "2018-04-27T09:08:04.428Z",
    "updatedAt" => "2018-07-14T14:28:17.771Z"
  },
  %{
    "artist" => "Al Green",
    "title" => "Let's Stay Together",
    "bpm" => 123,
    "createdAt" => "2018-04-27T09:08:04.428Z",
    "updatedAt" => "2018-07-14T14:28:17.771Z"
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: Can you try timing `Enum.sort_by(tracks, fn track -> first_char(track["title"]) end)`?

Comment: Blazingly fast! When I use `Enum.sort_by` as you suggested, `{time, result} = :timer.tc (fn -> MusicServer.Tracks.SortTracks.sort_tracks(tracks, "title", "desc") end)` gives me 7433, 6969, 6356 (microseconds)... Thanks!

Comment: And much more readable too!

Comment: I'm curious as to why this is. Any ideas, Dogbert?

Comment: At least, it's first calculates the first chars of every title and then starts to sort https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.7.2/lib/elixir/lib/enum.ex#L2308

Comment: so first_char(string) is called n times instead of number of comparisons (> n)

Comment: @ChristopheDeTroyer: From the `Enum.sort_by` [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#sort_by/3): *`sort_by/3` differs from `sort/2` in that it only calculates the comparison value for each element in the enumerable once instead of for each element in every comparison. (I changed the wording slightly to make it clearer what the docs are trying to say.)*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Enum.sort` will call the comparator function `n log(n)` times which means `first_char` will be called `2n log(n)` times which *might* be the bottleneck here. To reduce calls to `first_char`, you can switch to `Enum.sort_by` which calls the function once for each element and then caches its value when sorting:

```
Enum.sort_by(tracks, fn track -> first_char(track["title"]) end)
```

For a list of length 2,500, the number of calls to `first_char` would reduce from over 50k to 2.5k. Of course `sort_by` will have to do work work allocating data structure to store the computed values but it should still be faster for this input. You should carefully benchmark this yourself before using it!

Comment: Kudos for awareness of asymptotic (I think I got my term right) behavior characteristics!